# how to get python list from other list which has dict as elements

Tags: python

i have a list, i want get key=value in other list

for example:

```
my_list = [
    {'Key': 'Apple', 'Value': 'Fruit'},
    {'Key': 'Car', 'Value': 'Automobile'},
    {'Key': 'Dog', 'Value': 'Animal'},
    {'Key': 'Bolt', 'Value': 'Runner'}]
```

I have a my_list, i want to get output as:

```
new_list = ['Apple=Fruit', 'Car=Automobile', 'Dog=Animal', 'Bolt=Runner']
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with `join`

```
>>> my_list=[{'Key':'Apple','Value':'Fruit'},
    {'Key':'Car','Value':'Automobile'},
    {'Key':'Dog','Value':'Animal'},
    {'Key':'Bolt','Value':'Runner'}]
>>> new_list = ['='.join([i['Key'], i['Value']]) for i in my_list]
>>> new_list
['Apple=Fruit', 'Car=Automobile', 'Dog=Animal', 'Bolt=Runner']
```

I am a bit confused by your naming though. With the names `'Key'` and `'Value'` are you actually intending to make a `dict`? As your expected output is written (and my above code produces) it is a list of concatenated strings.

If you do indeed want to make a `dict` out of these, you can do something similar

```
my_list=[{'Key':'Apple','Value':'Fruit'},
    {'Key':'Car','Value':'Automobile'},
    {'Key':'Dog','Value':'Animal'},
    {'Key':'Bolt','Value':'Runner'}]
>>> new_dict = {i['Key'] : i['Value'] for i in my_list}
>>> new_dict
{'Car': 'Automobile', 'Bolt': 'Runner', 'Apple': 'Fruit', 'Dog': 'Animal'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation, using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>>  my_list=[{'Key': 'Apple', 'Value': 'Fruit'},
              {'Key': 'Car', 'Value': 'Automobile'},
              {'Key': 'Dog', 'Value': 'Animal'},
              {'Key': 'Bolt', 'Value': 'Runner'}]

>>> map(lambda d: "{Key}={Value}".format(**d), my_list)
['Apple=Fruit', 'Car=Automobile', 'Dog=Animal', 'Bolt=Runner']
```

Or (likely to be considerably more use in the long run):

```
>>> {d['Key']: d['Value'] for d in my_list}
{'Car': 'Automobile', 'Bolt': 'Runner', 'Apple': 'Fruit', 'Dog': 'Animal'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and accessing each dict's values

```
["{}={}".format(d.values()[1],d.values()[0]) for d in my_list]
['Apple=Fruit', 'Car=Automobile', 'Dog=Animal', 'Bolt=Runner']
```

Or using the keys:

```
["{}={}".format(d["Key"],d["Value"]) for d in my_list]
```